# Is there a way to manually restart the graphics drivers in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card

When graphics drivers crash in XP, but don't cause a blue screen, windows starts a fallback driver (I think it's 640x480 in 4-bit color). When that happens, is there any way to cause the original drivers to reload without having to restart the system? 
(I know Win7 does it for me automatically)

Comment: Sorry this aint linux but +1 for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, I think this was something new added in Vista or 7.

Comment: It was added in Vista, I believe.

Comment: It was added in Vista. That was one of the big reasons for the driver model change that happened in Vista.

Comment: Be thankful that your computer does a fallback and doesn't crash. At least then you have the chance to save your work before you restart. Try to update your garphics drivers so it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going into device manager, select your video card, then under the action menu select "scan for hardware changes".  That has worked for me for other devices needing plug and play to fire off so it might work for video cards.