# What does CTRL+WIN+SHIFT+B do in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Windows 10 and today I accidentally hit the key combination: 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

As a result, the screens went black for about a second and I heard a beep.

This is reproduceable; every time I hit the aforementioned key combination, the same behavior occurs.

Searching on the web I could find nothing about this except a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3iszu7/what_does_win_key_ctrl_b_do/) in which a user said he observed a similar behavior in Windows 8 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (no <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

So, what is this key combination used for?

Comment: [Interesting shortcut on Windows: Windows+Ctrl+Shift+B](https://matthijs.hoekstraonline.net/2016/11/08/interesting-shortcut-on-windows-windowsctrlshiftb/). It's also suggested by MS to recover from [the Chrome freezing bug](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3269789/windows/windows-10-april-2018-update-chrome-freeze.html)

Comment: ["This keycombo actually saves out part of the dispdiag circular log and queues up the data to upload through telemetry indicating the customer had a black screen."](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/6l7cyk/kb4022716_win_ctrl_shift_b_windows_10/djua1pi)

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of this shortcut, and I thought I was aware of nearly all. Is there any list available of secret, potentially useful tricks (i.e. keyboard shortcuts) like these?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> key sequence will restart your graphics driver.

Comment: I think that's it. After seeing your answer I found this: http://betanews.com/2016/11/14/how-to-restart-graphics-driver/ which confirms it.

Comment: If you have a Surface like I do, you probably also get to use this key combo every time you want to wake the machine from sleep...  If you don't do this, the monitors refuse to come back on!

Comment: @GolfWolf ah - it says the key combo only works on Win 10.  I confirm that on Win7 Pro it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can this be done with a console command too?

Comment: From a discussion with an AMD Radeon driver engineer, it does NOT restart the graphics driver. It does appear to discard the desktop surface buffer and re-create the allocation from DWM (on a healthy system the desktop goes black for a second).

Comment: Kevin's comment is correct. This key combo causes the Desktop Window Manager to recreate its graphics context and surface.

Comment: Why is there a shortcut for this? What's its common purpose?

Comment: @xr280xr One situation I have found this shortcut useful: On my Lenovo laptop, I occasionally get a glitch where maximizing any application causes a black bar across the top 1/4 or so of the screen.  This shortcut fixes it. (Discovered it here initially: https://thegeekpage.com/fix-maximized-window-blank-empty-space-on-top-of-screen-in-windows-10/ )

Answer (score 67):

Official [from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts):
"Windows logo key + Ctrl + Shift + B = [Wake PC from blank or black screen](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14106/windows-10-troubleshoot-black-screen-or-blank-screen-errors)"

From a discussion with an AMD Radeon driver engineer, it does NOT restart the graphics driver. It does appear to discard the desktop surface buffer and re-create the allocation from DWM (on a healthy system the desktop goes black for a second).

Comment: For what it's worth, Microsoft also recommends using it in this situation: when troubleshooting external monitor setup, when external monitor was working before but then suddenly stopped.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-external-monitor-connections-in-windows-10-5b46f4a4-9634-06bb-7622-f960facdfd49

Answer (score 5):

About a year and a half after OP asked their question, "SurfaceDockGuy" posted in reply to a similar Reddit question in /r/sysadmin,

> This keycombo actually saves out part of the dispdiag circular log and
> queues up the data to upload through telemetry indicating the customer
> had a black screen. That's what the "B" is for. Blackscreen.
>
> The key combo was added to help diagnose instances where the machine
> is churning along but there is nothing on screen. Pressing it when you
> don't have a blackscreen just adds noise to the system. A driver reset
> is a possible side-effect but not the intent of this key.
>
> Source: I worked on the team at MS.

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/6l7cyk/comment/djua1pi/

Answer (score 1):

Have only found this one, [please take a look](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/the-complete-list-of-windows-logo-keyboard-shortcuts/):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> -> 
Switch to the program that displayed a message in the notification area.

Comment: Yes, I ran into that while searching. I even use Win+B occasionally (although not with the CTRL version). However, if I add shift on top of that I get the totally weird behavior I described in the question.

Comment: While not the best answer, spreading this handy tip is still useful. +1

Comment: Your answer has no relation to the original question which was 
"What does Ctrl+Win+ **SHIFT** +B do in Windows".