# All chrome windows suddenly turned completely black, probably GPU Glitch

Tags: google-chrome, gpu

I've launched Chrome explicitly forcing it to use the dedicated GPU in my laptop.

After a while a sudden graphical glitch occured, which turned all the open Chrome windows completely black including the url bar and the tabs section, only an outline of the window remained.

The pages were still responsive thought, because when I pressed space while the window in which spotify was open was focused, the music started playing.

I could've just restarted the browser and it would most likely return to normal that way, but I had information on a few pages that were important to me and would be lost after a restart, so I was looking for a way to preserve that data.

Comment: Make and model of laptop? (Please use model number from the sticker which also has the serial number; other locations have 'marketing model' numbers which don't help.) Operating system name and version? Graphics card and drivers in use? Please click [edit] and enhance your question so others may have information they may need to help. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I first restarted my graphics drivers using the [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> key combination](https://superuser.com/questions/1127463/what-does-ctrlwinshiftb-do-in-windows), which didn't immediately solve the issue, but after this I tried opening a new window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to see if only the already existing windows are broken and the newly created ones are free from the issue or those are affected as well, and to my surprise this action brought all the previously black windows back to life as well!

I don't know whether the graphics driver restart was a necessary step or not, but this combination solved my problem and I was able to recover the information.

Comment: It sounds like a powersaving state causes the graphics card to go inactive. If this is the case, this will come back. CTRL-N will likely have woken up the graphics card. I would suggest to set it back so the graphics card is not used for chrome.