# Top bar missing from applications in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, microsoft-teams

User on my estate is having a strange issue in that the entire top bar of applications vanishes. Completely too, so not hidden and just contains a white box.

Its happened at first to just chrome and then egde with the tabs, favourites and navigation bars vanishing, and now teams too.

Teams missing top bar:[image]

(Ignore the black border; It is to make the "white box" distinct)

I have tried a reset on both of the browsers and it appears to fix the issue for a short while, as does a restart, but it always returns. No other graphical glitches have appeared and the graphics drivers are up-to-date.

Comment: Too strange. Probably some installed application or virus infection.

Comment: Don't forget that Teams is actually a web-app that renders in an embedded browser (Chromium based IIRC). As Edge is also Chromium based the culprit could be some malware that messages with Chromium windows. Wouldn't surprise me if VisualStudio Code has issues too.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> and the letter <kbd>B</kbd> at the same time. You'll hear a quick beep and monitor will go black for one second, but should resolve issue.

This restarts the graphic driver as answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1127463/what-does-ctrlwinshiftb-do-in-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Its apparently some conflict between the hardware and the code, a workaround was to change the screen resolution, then put it back again to save shutting down all the time.

Also tried turning off hardware acceleration. User seems happy.

No virus or addons were on the machine!