# Detect displays in Windows 10 without opening settings (using a script command?)

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, script

When I lock or sleep my computer and unlock it again later, one of my three monitors does not always turn on. Settings -> Display has a "Detect" button that turns on all monitors handily (though merely navigating there by using "Rearrange multiple displays" usually wakes up all monitors, so it probably runs detection on open). However, I would rather not have to open Settings every time.

Optimally, Windows would detect all monitors automatically when the computer wakes up, but I suspect that Windows would have implemented this if it were that easy. The most obvious alternative to me is to write a script using the command the Detect button triggers, then binding a key combination to a shortcut to that script.

What command can I call from a script to do the same thing as clicking the "Detect" button in Display Settings? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: First thing I would try is in a **PowerShell** console: `Get-PnpDevice -Class Monitor`.

Comment: @KeithMiller Thanks, I'll try it next time the issue appears.

Comment: @KeithMiller I tried that command as a PowerShell script when only two monitors turned on. It didn't succeed in turning on the last one, but, once again, opening "Rearrange multiple displays" from the Start menu did.

Comment: Was it listed, even if it didn't on?

Comment: @KeithMiller It was listed, but I want Windows to detect the monitor. I already know it's there.

Comment: Edited question to eliminate that misunderstanding.

Comment: Windows support suggests trying Ctrl + WinKey + Shift + B, which is supposed to "Wake PC from blank or black screen", says https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10. I'll test that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> refreshed my monitors and awoke the one that didn't awaken at first. Microsoft support suggested it.

Comment: For anyone wondering what it does: [It restarts the graphics driver](https://superuser.com/a/1145620).