# Is this colour aberration due to the screen dying?

Tags: display, nvidia-geforce

I have an NVIDIA GTX 1630 card, with three screens connected to it.

A few months ago, one of my 3 screens started showing a colour aberration.  It's more pronounced when f.lux is on.

It looks like thousands of little beacons.  Does anyone know what the cause might be?

Screen of Concern

[image]

Normal Screen

[image]

1. It does not show in screenshots.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> fixed it.
3. After doing the above it has not happened again.
4. My drivers are always current.

Comment: Have you tried using a different HDMI/DP cable?

Comment: That was also my first idea. You can switch the cable of 2 monitors and see if the problem moves to a different screen. Another thing you can try is CTRL-WIN-SHIFT-B, this will reinitialize your graphics driver. (all screens will go black for about 3 seconds)

Comment: Does it show in a screen-shot?

Comment: @Tetsujin, Great question, it doesn't.  Which is why I used my camera.

Comment: Proves it's not software… but little else. I'd try the re-wiring in a different order, see if it follows the cable or the GPU socket or if it's limited to that one display no matter how it's cabled.

Comment: @LPChip, the re-initialize fixes it.  Any suggestions on the cause?  Now, I have to wait for it to happen again, before swapping cables.

Comment: If the reinit fixes it, then its a driver issue. Update those.

Answer (score 1):

Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> fixes the issue, and the only thing [that keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/1127463/what-does-ctrlwinshiftb-do-in-windows) does is discard the screen buffer and recreate it, then likely the issue is between the graphics chips and the monitor. To confirm this, switch cables **at the monitor** between the problematic monitor and another, and see if the issue now occurs on the one that was working well.

If a different monitor now shows the defect, then look to the cables and to the PC. For example, is video output through the same type of port (DVI, HDMI, etc.) for each display? Perhaps the PC has trouble with one port type, or a cable is bad.

If the monitor that had the issue *still* does, then it is possible the issue is elsewhere.